# Not need CSRF feature in django 1.2.3

Tags: python, django

I upgrading from django 1.1.1 to django 1.2.3, I know that CSRF feature have changed. But I don't need this feature for now , How can I make my code run properly.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the corresponding middleware from the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` constant in your settings file.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Comment: but i use a code written by django 1.1.1, so django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware didnt appear.